# Conditional overloading operator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I am using python 3 (3.3, but I'm interested of any nice solution, even if it's only python 3.4 or more).
I want to create a custom class with conditional overloading operator like that:

```
class test :
    def __init__(self,overload) :
         if overload :
             self.__add__=lambda x,y : print("OK")
             self.f=lambda : print(True)
    def f(self) : print(False)

t=test(False)
t.f() #print False as expected
u=test(True)
u.f() #print True as expected
u+u #fails as if it was not implemented
```

After some digging, I realized that operator `+` does not call `__add__` on the object, but on the class. Hence, I can't do it like that **(or can I)?**

So I can define something like that :

```
class test :
    def __init__(self,overload) :
        self.overload=overload
    def __add__(self,other) :
        if self.overload : print("OK")
        else #FAILURE
    def f(self) : print(self.overload)
```

But **what can I put** into the `FAILURE` statement such that it fails exactly like if it was not implemented? For example, if it fails, I'll be happy if it tried `__radd__` on the second operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, special methods are looked up on the type and you cannot set them on the instance.

If you want to not always support `.__add__` return the `NotImplemented` singleton:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, overload):
        self.overload = overload

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not self.overload:
            return NotImplemented
        print("Ok")
```

Returning `NotImplemented` from a rich comparison method makes Python behave as if there was no such method; usually this is used to signal that the *type* of `other` isn't supported, but you are free to return it when you don't want to support the operation *just now*.

Note that Python will still try the reverse operation; for `test() + something`, Python first tries `test().__add__(something)`, then `something.__radd__(test())` is called if the first operation returned `NotImplemented`. If the latter doesn't exist or also returns `NotImplemented`, a `TypeError` is raised.

Demo:

```
>>> class test:
...     def __init__(self, overload):
...         self.overload = overload
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         if not self.overload:
...             return NotImplemented
...         print("Ok")
... 
>>> test(False) + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'int'
>>> test(True) + 1
Ok
```

Comment: I would rather expect that to raise a `TypeError`, like for example `1 + 'a'` does.

Comment: @LukasGraf: **Python** raises `TypeError` because `int.__add__` *and* `str.__radd__` return `NotImplemented` when passing in an unsupported `other` argument.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Raising `TypeError` yourself is the *wrong thing to do*, because then Python doesn't get to try `other.__radd__(first)`.